# Java program processing non-letter characters

Tags: java, encryption, char, int, ascii

UPDATED TO CHANGE ONE SEGMENT FROM ANDS TO ORS

I am trying to program a Cipher program, so far, it encrypts letters so far, but I cannot get it to ignore non-letter characters.  I have an if statement that is supposed to handle that, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Cipher {

private String phrase; // phrase that will be encrypted 
private int shift; //number that shifts the letters


///////////////
//Constructor//
//////////////

public Cipher( int new_shift)
{

    shift = new_shift;



}//end of cipher constructor


////////////
//Accessor//
////////////

public int askShift() {


return shift;
}//end of askShift accessor

////////////
//mutators//
////////////

public void changeShift (int newShift) {

shift = newShift;

}//end of changeShift mutator

/////////////
//instances//
/////////////

public String encryptIt(String message) {

char[] charArray = message.toCharArray(); //converts to a character array
int[] asciiArray = new int[charArray.length]; //array to store the ascii codes

//for loop that converts the charArray into an integer array
for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {

    asciiArray[count] = charArray[count];

} //end of For Loop

//loop that performs the encryption
for (int count = 0; count < asciiArray.length; count++) {
//these numbered equality statements check to see if the ascii code is a non-character. If it is, continue the loop

    if (asciiArray[count] < 65 || asciiArray[count] > 90 || asciiArray[count] < 96 || asciiArray[count] > 122){
    continue;
    }
    else
    asciiArray[count] = ((asciiArray[count]- 97)+ shift) % 26 + 97;{
    }
} //end of for loop

 //loop that converts the int array back into a character array
    for (int count = 0; count < asciiArray.length; count++) {

            charArray[count] = (char)asciiArray[count];

    }

/* commenting out this block until futher notice
//loop that performs the encryption
for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {
int shiftNum = 2;
charArray[count] = (char)(((charArray[count] - 'a') + shiftNum) % 26 + 'a');

} // end of for loop */ 

 message = new String(charArray); //converts the array to a string



return message;
}//end of encrypt instance 


//////////
///Main///
//////////
public static void main(String[] args) {

Cipher cipher = new Cipher(1); //cipher with a shift of one letter
Cipher cipher2 = new Cipher(5); //cipher with a shift of two letters
String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter phrase to be messed with ");
String encryption = cipher.encryptIt(phrase);
String encryption2 = cipher2.encryptIt(phrase);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, encryption);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, encryption2);



}//end of main function



} //end of cipher class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change condition inside your `if`

EDITED:

`if ((asciiArray[count] < 65 || asciiArray[count] > 90) && (asciiArray[count] < 96 || asciiArray[count] > 122))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in this line:

`if (asciiArray[count] < 65 && asciiArray[count] > 90 && asciiArray[count] < 96 && asciiArray[count] > 122)`

You are saying that if a number is less than 65, and it is greater than 90 and that if it is less than 96 and greater than 122... You would need to replace those AND conditions with OR since as it is now, it will always evaluate to false.

Also, another way of going around this would be that since `charArray` contains the character values, you could use the [`Character.isLetter(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) instead, so your code becomes:

```
if(Character.isLetter(charArray[count])){
asciiArray[count] = ((asciiArray[count]- 97)+ shift) % 26 + 97;
}
```

Note that as your program is now, you seem to have a misplaced `{` in the `else` block.

Comment: I changed it to ||, but then the encryption doesn't work at all.

Comment: @user1768884: You need to be more specific. Also, you can try my other suggestion.